# javascript iterating over array and feeding into another function

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, fullcalendar

I'm populating a FullCalendar.io instance and drawing the data from the Wordpress REST API on my site to do so.

I am able to carry out an XHR request and return the relevant data in an array *myData*.

Events are added as so:

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl,
      {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        events: [
           {
             title: 'Event Title2',
             start: $start,
             end: '2021-04-08T13:13:55-0400',
           }
         ],
      });
      calendar.render();
      }
    });
```

This is in a script tag in the header and being rendered to the page to a div #calendar.

$start is correctly interpolated and rendered when using `let $start = myData[0].acf.start;`

However, I want to iterate over *myData* and return an object, which I am able to console log, but unable to then feed into the options under `events:`

```
        function myFunction(element) {
        let x = element.acf.start;
        let y = element.acf.end;
        let title1 = element.title.rendered;
        var event = {title: title1, start: y, end: x};
      
        //return event;
```

I tried putting in a correctly formed javascript opject into the `events:` array but it doesn't work. Neither does trying to call myFunction().

I had errors such as $start is not defined, so I tried moving it below to make it globally available (by calling it before the function has defined it).

I want to have an object for each event correctly rendered in the events option for the calendar.

How can I get all my events into the calendar and not just the latest one , eg instead of myData[0].acf.start, being able to access .acf.start for every item in the myData array and returning it to the events array?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: create a fiddle with your issues

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating it. Read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function - you can run the XHR request in there, get the events, transform them into fullCalendar format and pass them to the calendar via the provided callback. FullCalendar will re-run this every time the date range changes in the calendar, so you should ensure the server-side code only returns events which match the dates provided by fullCalendar.

Comment: @ADyson My events are available as a json feed with the standard wordpress rest api. I have added the following to my code as per the documentation

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed

  ```var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    events: 'http://svc.local/wp-json/wp/v2/event'
  });``` but I get Uncaught ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined. As far as I know my files are imported correctly or the calendar wouldn't display at all. I tried to swap for FullCalendar but it said not a constructor. Any idea what the issue is? Thank you

Comment: @Vel Please see JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zdawg/78e5v2rx/

Comment: That isn't at all what I suggested you should do. And I doubt it would work anyway because looking at your other code the data doesn't seem to be in the format fullCalendar needs. that's why you need to follow the process I suggested where you download it yourself within the callback, transform it using JavaScript and then pass it back to fullCalendar. Also you don't need to declare a while new calendar for doing that. It needs to be within you existing calendar config!

Comment: @ADyson granted; I've updated the fiddle with the latest code and as per the link in your comment, I'm not getting any events rendered though, can you see what is wrong? Thank you so much

Comment: I can only see a link to https://jsfiddle.net/zdawg/78e5v2rx/ which doesn't contain anything new. Do you have a link to a newer version?

Comment: @ADyson ah ok, i did another one here hopefully that works : https://jsfiddle.net/zdawg/5ucghabw/ thank you

Comment: Well it's all very confusing because `https://svc.local/wp-json/wp/v2/event` is never going to return anything in a JSFiddle anyway - it almost certainly cannot access that URL, and also you're still doing the AJAX outside the fullCalendar callback, and also it's unclear how you think myFunc is ever going to be executed? I feel like maybe there are some JavaScript fundamentals that you're not quite grasping here.

Comment: Anyway I was expecting something more like this: https://jsfiddle.net/quy0sd26/1/  . That should work assuming that a) the url is accessible, and b) the data is returned in the expected format, including things like dates being in a format that fullCalendar can understand. I haven't seen any samples of the data returned by the API, so I can't comment on that, but you can compare it with what's listed as valid in the fullCalendar documentation. If it's not 100% there yet, it at least gives you the correct structure, so you could then go on to debug it until it's completely right.

Comment: @ADyson That's perfect that's working. Yes next time I'll make that data available from a live site. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Read fullCalendar's [Events as a Function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) article. This provides you with the ability to define a re-usable callback function to get the events. So within that callback you can run the AJAX request, get the events, transform them into fullCalendar format and pass them to the calendar via the provided "success" callback function.

FullCalendar will re-run this every time the date range changes in the calendar, so you should ensure the server-side code only returns events which match the dates provided by fullCalendar.

Something like this:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl,
    {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      events: function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
        let url = 'https://svc.local/wp-json/wp/v2/event?' + new URLSearchParams({
          start: info.startStr,
          end: info.endStr
        });

        fetch(url)
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(jsonResponse) {
          // do something with jsonResponse
          console.log(jsonResponse);
          var events = [];

          jsonResponse.forEach(function(el) {
            var event = {
              start: el.acf.start,
              end: el.acf.end,
              title: el.title.rendered
            };
            events.push(event);
          });
        
          successCallback(events);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          failureCallback(err);
        });
      }
    });

    calendar.render();
});
```